# Replace a part of html string using regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

In trying to replace parts of a string using a regex.

This is my string

```
"<p>0</p>
<p>0</p> 
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>1</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>3</p>"
```

and im doing this

```
aboveString.replace('/<p>\&nbsp;<\/p>/g','<br style="clear:both;" />')
```

I need to replace all instances of the

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

to be replaced with

```
<br style="clear:both;" />
```

Can you please tell me where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex `'/<p>\&nbsp;<\/p>/g'` isn't a regex, it's a string. Remove the quotes to make it a regex literal:

```
aboveString.replace(/<p>\&nbsp;<\/p>/g,'<br style="clear:both;" />')
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pTqgX/

Comment: aarghhh :( :( that hurt

Answer (score 3):

I know, its about Regex, but its so obviously doable without Regex:

```
aboveString.split('<p>&nbsp;</p>').join('<br style="clear:both;" />');
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PkfEr/)**</kbd>

Now downvote me, friends

Answer (score 2):

```
aboveString.replace(/<p>\&nbsp;<\/p>/g,'<br style="clear:both;" />')
```

in Javascript u don't write regexp inside `""`. Every thing written within `""` is treated as String. **:)**